# Adaptive cards for MS Teams - images displaying in web interface but not desktop application

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a recurring issue with teams and adaptive cards. It doesn't seem to matter if I post a card from the Flow post an adaptive card connector or from the graph API directly, the images in my cards display in the teams web browser interface but not in the desktop application.

Apart from that the card displays ok, just no image rendering in desktop. Tough one to debug as it's working ok in chrome, if there a way to look at the desktop apps source code to see if that img url is being prefixed or replaced or something down those lines.

Curious thing is I've seen a couple of videos of it working for others but. Here's my card code within the Graph API body JSON...

```
{
"subject": null,
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<attachment id=\"74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5\"></attachment>"
},
"attachments": [
    {
        "id": "74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "contentUrl": null,
        "content": "{ \"type\": \"AdaptiveCard\", \"body\": [ { 
        \"type\": \"TextBlock\",
        \"size\": \"Medium\",
        \"weight\": \"Bolder\",
        \"text\": \"Hello andy\"
    },
    {
        \"type\": \"Image\",
        \"altText\": \"\",
        \"url\": \"https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamsDev/ImageLib/imagebname.jpg\"
    }
],
\"$schema\": \"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json\",
\"version\": \"1.0\"
}",
        "name": null,
        "thumbnailUrl": null
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but just a guess - perhaps because the image is stored on SharePoint, which is secured. In the browser, the user has a signed-in session to SharePoint, but perhaps that's not respected in the Teams client. Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks again for your help Hilton, if you help me any more this week i've have to pay you a consultants fee :), looks like you are absolutely right and I should have thought of that, I was thinking Teams would like the fact it's an HTTPS url, didnt consider that the app wouldnt have the authentication of course!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. Will log as a proper answer then in fact, so others can find it in future. Lol about consulting fees - just tell me where to send the invoice ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, this was because of the image Url - it's a SharePoint Url , so silently uses the users login session in the web client, but doesn't do the same in the desktop client.

Comment: i have some other image url. https://shop.havells.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/_/0_287_3_6512.jpg This image url also not working in team. What is the reason

Comment: You should always be able to browse the image anonymously - i.e. just by loading the image directly in the browser. If I try your link above, it gives an error.

Comment: But I can able to load this image on my browser. It is not giving any error for me

Comment: try load it in an InPrivate session. Maybe you have a saved session credential or something

Comment: I tried in different browsers, chrome incognito window safari private window . still image is loading

Comment: I get this error: "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.
Your support ID is: 226267759824609780". Perhaps it's based on the region you are browsing from - that could be another reason for failure - images in Teams are handled by the Teams service pre-fetching and then caching them in a CDN, so if it can't reach the image for any reason, it will fail. I've even had this happen on an endpoint that only supported TLS 1.3, which Teams was unhappy with .

Comment: Thanks for you response. It helps :)

Comment: great, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, When you try to load an image within Adaptive Card using sharepoint url, It uses the accessToken in the images url (which you can see if you try to debug) when you load the adaptive card in Teams Web version with the same user credentails it will work because session But this same behavior will not work with Teams Desktop client. Better to put the images in solution itself and use from there.

Comment: i have some other image url. https://shop.havells.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/_/0_287_3_6512.jpg This image url also not working in team. What is the reason