# Images hosted in share point aren't displaying when posted to team via webhook

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to migrate some of our reports from slack to Microsoft Teams.
We are currently posting images and csv files to slack from an Azure Function.

Early on I noticed that I cannot post images directly but I can mention their URLs in the card and a preview displays and clicking on it should take me to the actual image.
I started out thinking it would be pretty straightforward. And i went ahead and started with the webhooks option. The only problem is that the it supports only 2 types of cards and i have virtually no control over the image size and other properties. And if I'm to use the Adaptive Card(any other card), then I would have to ditch webhooks and make use of the Graph API, which I've already started.

Then I started noticing that the images disappear, as in they just not get displayed anymore. I believe that this could be an authentication issue between sharepoint/ teams as mentioned in this answer -
[Adaptive cards for MS Teams - images displaying in web interface but not desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970103/adaptive-cards-for-ms-teams-images-displaying-in-web-interface-but-not-desktop)

Teams in browser shows the images but the desktop app doesn't. Also they aren't displaying in my mobile app for teams too.

I have already modified my existing application to send a copy of the image/file (whatever it creates) to a folder inside the sharepoint which is the back end to this channel in teams (used sharepoint API v1)
And I intend to post a thumbnail card with a url to the images/file in Sharepoint.

It would really help if someone could help me with the below :

1. Anyway to fix the authentication issue between Sharepoint ~ Teams
2. Alternate options to send an image, if 1. is not feasible.

Please help :)

Edit :
Adding card JSON :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Sample Heading",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "auto",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ea/FlowersForAlgernon.jpg",
                                    "size": "medium"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Report1",
                                    "text": "Matt Hidinger",
                                    "weight": "bolder",
                                    "wrap": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "spacing": "none",
                                    "text": "Created {{DATE(2020-02-14T06:08:39Z,SHORT)}}",
                                    "isSubtle": true,
                                    "wrap": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Adaptive cards are now supported in Incoming webhook. For sending adaptive cards using Incoming Webhooks, You need to follow the Bot Activity Message Type format: [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egM7r.png). 
where you can add the card json <card json>  to the content field.
**Note**: Also, this type "type": "Report1" in the your payload is invalid as there is no type "Report1" in Adaptive card, Could you please try by using correct type?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I have done as you've asked, using webhooks - but when I use adaptive cards it ends up with the below error : 
_Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400 with ContextId MS-CV=iKFnc/DCwEmMhiAOhBMwIw.0.._

Comment: [Error] (https://imgur.com/a/lM7eNgU)

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive cards are now supported on Incoming webhook. For sending adaptive cards using Incoming Webhooks, You need to follow the Bot Activity Message Type format: [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egM7r.png). where you can add the card json  to the content field.

Example:

Post Web-hook URL

Request Body:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Sample Heading",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "auto",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ea/FlowersForAlgernon.jpg",
                                    "size": "medium"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "Matt Hidinger",
                                    "weight": "bolder",
                                    "wrap": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "spacing": "none",
                                    "text": "Created {{DATE(2020-02-14T06:08:39Z,SHORT)}}",
                                    "isSubtle": true,
                                    "wrap": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:
[image]